# python data not insert into sqlite database errors found

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

hi i want to insert into data into sqlite data doesn't insert.
error message

[image]

> **MY function inside Code**

```
def addstudent(self):

        b2 = self.a2.text()
        b3 = self.a3.text()
        b4 = self.a4.text()
        b5 = self.a5.text()
        b6 = self.a6.text()
        b7 = self.a7.text()
        b8 = self.a8.text()
        b9 = self.a9.itemText(self.a9.currentIndex())
        b10 = self.a10.itemText(self.a10.currentIndex())
        b11 = self.a11.itemText(self.a11.currentIndex())
        b12 = self.a12.text()
        b13 = self.a13.itemText(self.a13.currentIndex())
        b14 = self.a14.itemText(self.a14.currentIndex())
        b15 = self.a15.text()
        b16 = self.a16.itemText(self.a16.currentIndex())
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect("collage_App.db")
            dbs = conn.cursor()
            dbs.execute("""INSERT INTO student_registration VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, , ?, ?) """ , (b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16, arrow.now().format('YYYY-MM-DD')) )
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

            QMessageBox.information(QMessageBox(),'Successful','Student is added successfully into database.')
            self.close()
        except Exception:
            QMessageBox.warning(QMessageBox(), 'Error', 'Could not add student to the database.')
```

> **My Button Event Code**

```
#Submit Button Clicked
        self.add.clicked.connect(self.addstudent)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error message you have posted is the error message you wrote in your own code. You are hiding the true error behind your own error handling. Remove the try/except block and you'll get a full stack trace with details of the real error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the try-except clauses and post the actual error.

On the other hand, you'd be better off using Django for working with Databases. Check their tutorial at https://www.djangoproject.com/start/. It's much less error-prone and provides a great interface for working with models.

Comment: i have removed try catch now console error  **  Exception "unhandled sqlite3.IntegrityError"
datatype mismatch
File: C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\Eric6\collageApp\ui\Ui_registerStudent.py, Line: 729
 **

Comment: It basically means that one of the data types that you've provided doesn't match what the database schema requires i.e. database requires "City" to be of type String while you've given it an Integer.

You should name those fields differently than "a" or "b" as it will get very hard to find an error in your code later on.